# What is the probability that each of the four candies selected is of a different type?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Today on my probability midterm I had this question:

You have a bag of 20 candies, composed of 5 candies of 4 different flavours. There's 5 candies with lemon flavor, 5 candies with orange, 5 candies with cherry and 5 candies with apple flavour. You randomly pick four of these candies.

a) What's the probability that they're all the same?

b) What's the probability that they're all different?

c) What's the probability you select two of one type, and two of another (so like cherry, cherry && apple, apple)?

For part A I did 4*(5/20)(4/19)(3/18)(2/17)(1/16), but I had no clue how to deal with parts b and c. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your answer to a is incorrect. A correct answer is supplied below!

Answer (score 2):

a) You only pick four candies yet your equation consists of 5 terms, which is incorrect. It should be ${4\choose1}{5\choose4}\over{20\choose4}$$=4({5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\over20\cdot19\cdot18\cdot17})$. Note there is no $16$ in the denominator.

b) You basically choose one from each flavour, so the possibility is ${4\choose4}{5\choose1}^4\over{20\choose4}$.

c) You first choose two types and then choose two from each type, you have ${4\choose2}{5\choose2}^2\over{20\choose4}$.